# Maths Quiz Task 3 Saving 3 scores on one name

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone knows how to save three scores onto one name for maths quiz task 3.

sample of code:

```
if student_class == '1':   
  file = open("Results(1).txt","a")  
  student_results = ' name: '+student_name+' , score: ' +str(score) +'\n' #  
  file.write(student_results)
  file.close() 

if student_class == '2': following code will be produced
  file = open("Results(2).txt","a")
  student_results = ' name: '+student_name+' , score: ' +str(score) +'\n' 
  file.write(student_results)
  file.close()

if student_class == '3': 
  file = open("Results(3).txt","a") 
  student_results = ' name: '+student_name+' , score: ' +str(score) +'\n' 
  file.write(student_results)
  file.close()
```

Comment: Your indentation cannot be right, please fix it. What is in `Results(1).txt` and the other files? It seems important for your question. What output do you want? (Do not answer in a comment; this information should be [edit]ed into the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating the same code, so you can use string formatting to not do that

```
with open("Results({}).txt".format(student_class),"a") as file:
    student_results = ' name: '+student_name+' , score: ' +str(score) +'\n' #  
    file.write(student_results)
```

If you want all classes in one file, then remove the condition on your class variable

If you want three scores in a file for a name, you would just use `file.write()` three times with the same name, but different scores